# A grammatical quiz I can not answer: "known by making" vs. "known to make"

Tags: prepositions, infinitive-vs-gerund

Please let me know which sentence is correct.

> 1. Chocolate is known **by making** people feel happier. OR
> 2. Chocolate is known **to make** people feel happier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Chocolate is known to make people feel happier

As explained [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-known-to-be-do-sth).

"By" would be if someone *knew* the subject, in the passive form

> The properties of chocolate are known by scientists

i.e.

> Scientists know the properties of chocolate